# Is there a way to add a custom up to date condition while preserving the original one?

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

Say that I am using a Gradle plugin that defines task `foo`, which is up to date under a certain condition. Unfortunately, I don't have the source, so I don't know when it is.

I would like to make it so that `foo` is up to date if the original condition is true, and if a custom condition is also true.

I know I can add my custom condition like this:

```
foo.outputs.upToDateWhen {
    return myCondition == true
}
```

But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
foo.outputs.upToDateWhen {
    return super.upToDateWhen && myCondition == true
}
```

Is there any way to do what I am looking for? Can I add an up to date condition in such a way that I can have it preserve the original up to date condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is actually the default behaviour. The description of the `upToDateWhen` method in [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html#upToDateWhen(groovy.lang.Closure)) is:

> Adds a predicate to determine whether the outputs of this task are up-to-date. The given closure is executed at task execution time. The closure is passed the task as a parameter. If the closure returns false, the task outputs are considered out-of-date and the task will be executed.
>
> You can add multiple such predicates. The task outputs are considered out-of-date when any predicate returns false.